# Adding bar labels with subscript to a barplot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm trying to create a `barplot` where the bar labels include subscript.

I know how to insert text for `titles`/`axis` labels with subscript using the expression function
e.g.:

```
mtext(side=2,expression("LD"[5]))
```

but how does one create a vector where some objects in the vector will show up on the plot axis as subscript when the vector is used for the bar names?

Comment: You can label the bars in `barplot` using a similar `expression` as above using the `names.arg` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a standard character vector to specify names, you must use an expression vector. For example

```
barplot(VADeaths, names.arg=expression(x[i], x[2], "Male","Female"))
```

So the values that are not quoted are treated as expression and will get the fancy math plotting treatment. Those in quote will be plotted as basic text.

[image: sample barplot with math labels]